# How to assert both UserWarning and SystemExit in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, systemexit, user-warning

**Assert UserWarning and SystemExit in pytest**

In my application I have a function that when provided with wrong argument values will raise a `UserWarnings` from `warnings` module and then raises `SystemExit` from `sys` module.

**Code is something like:**

```
def compare_tags(.....):

    requested_tags = user_requested_tags # as list
    all_tags = tags_calculated_from_input_file  # as list 

    non_matching_key = [x for x in requested_tags if x not in all_tags]

    # if user requested non existing tag then raise warning and then exit 
    if len(non_matching_key) > 0:

        # generate warning
        warnings.warn("The requested '%s' keys from '%s' is not present in the input file. Please makes sure the input file has the metadata of interest or remove the non matching keys." %(non_matching_key, given_tags))

        # raise system exit
        sys.exit(0)
```

**writing a pytest for above function**

I want to test this `UserWarning` and `SystemExit` in pytest at once. I can check for `SystemExit` in the pytest as.

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
    compare_tags(....)
```

but this will also dispaly a warning message (which is not an error).

If I want to check for warnings:

```
pytest.warns(UserWarning, 
    compare_tags(...)
```

This will generate a `SystemExit` error because this called function will trigger system exit.

**How can I put both the `warnings` and `SystemExit` check in the same pytest?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pytest.warns` and `pytest.raises` are the usual context managers and can be declared in a single `with` statement when separated with a comma (see [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)):

```
with pytest.warns(UserWarning), pytest.raises(SystemExit):
    compare_tags(...)
```

which is effectively the same as writing

```
with pytest.warns(UserWarning):
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
        compare_tags(...)
```

Notice that **the order matters** - when you put both context managers in the reverse order:

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit), pytest.warns(UserWarning):
    ...
```

this is the same as writing

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
    with pytest.warns(UserWarning):
        ...
```

The problem here is that `pytest.raises` will capture all raised errors and then check for what's captured. This includes what `pytest.warns` raises. This means that

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit), pytest.warns(UserWarning):
    sys.exit(0)
```

will pass because the error raised in `pytest.warns` will be swallowed in `pytest.raises`, while

```
with pytest.warns(UserWarning), pytest.raises(SystemExit):
    sys.exit(0)
```

will fail as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest two exceptions like this:

```
def test_exit():
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
        error_msg = "warning here"
        with pytest.warns(UserWarning, match = error_msg):
            compare_tags(...)
```